# Is a question about a payment policy appropriate on any SE site?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, site-recommendation

Is there any SE site where the following question is acceptable?

---

Walmart in my area requires ID for any credit card transaction, even though this is strictly prohibited by Visa, Mastercard, and other primary credit card companies. I'd like to argue this policy, but am I justified to do so on grounds that Visa prohibits this requirement?

Comment: Sounds like a legal question, and legal questions generally have no place on the Stack Exchange network. But as far as I'm aware, you're supposed to report violations like that to the credit card company and let them handle the situation.

Comment: Submit a complaint to the credit card company.  http://www.mastercard.us/support/merchant-violations.html  Name and shame the company in a blog or on twitter.  Find an appropriate online-review site and complain about them.